# Join tables keeping empty results

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables that I need to cross and return as many results as the ids of one of them.

The first is a table of roles/tasks:

```
id | rolename
---+---------
1  | check_in
2  | cleaning
3  | taxi
4  | guide
5  | car_rental
6  | meals
7  | house_owner
20 | custom
```

and another table that has the columns:

```
id | client_booking_id | staff_role_id | confirmed | staff_cost
```

I need a query that always gives me as many results as nr of columns in the first table. Because for each unique `client_booking_id` there will be only one (if any) of those tasks/roles.

So if I do:

```
SELECT sr.role_name, sr.id, ss.staff_cost, ss.confirmed 
    FROM staff_role AS sr
    LEFT JOIN staff_schedule AS ss ON sr.id=ss.staff_role_id
```

I get a result with the nr of rows I want. Now I need to match it with a specific `client_booking_id` so I did

```
SELECT sr.role_name, sr.id, ss.staff_cost, ss.confirmed 
    FROM staff_role AS sr
    LEFT JOIN staff_schedule AS ss ON sr.id=ss.staff_role_id
    WHERE ss.client_booking_id=1551 // <-- this is the new line
```

And this gives me only 2 results because in the second table I have only booked 2 tasks to a `id`.

But I need a result with all tasks even those that do not match, with `NULL` values. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your query (*without `where` clause*) you get rows with `null` and non-`null` values for `client_booking_id`. You want to match specific  `client_booking_id` and at the same time leave all records with `null` values, so you add additional condition with specific `client_booking_id` to `left join`.

Moving condition to `left join`:

```
select sr.role_name
     , sr.id
     , ss.staff_cost
     , ss.confirmed 
from staff_role sr
left join staff_schedule ss on sr.id = ss.staff_role_id
                           and ss.client_booking_id = 1551
```

Comment: The first query is correct.  The second is incorrect; it will remove rows when there are other client booking ids.